# Sound (English voice) assets for my game

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, 2d-games

I'm developing a rather simple game for kids but it needs to have proper English voiceover. Anyone knows where I can get one? I guess there should be companies that could make such recordings for a fee, but I failed to google for any.

Comment: Just google for "voiceover artist" there are thousands, add "freelance" for cheaper.

Answer (score 1):

Try to google for "Sound design" studio. These companies provides a wide range of services related to sound, voice and music.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

The sound design for my games always comes from Canners Mediaproductions. Thats a dutch company, located in Amsterdam.